# how to set best_compression when creating an index in elasticsearch using NEST

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to implement this when I create a new index in elasticsearch using NEST 5.x:

> index.codec
>   The default value compresses stored data with LZ4 compression, but this can be set to best_compression which uses DEFLATE for a higher compression ratio, at the expense of slower stored fields performance.

Here is my code:

```
 var createIndexResponse = client.CreateIndex("index-name", c => c
        .Settings(s => s.Setting("index.codec", "best_compression"))
        .Mappings(m => m
            .Map<Conference>(d => d
                .AutoMap()
            )
        )
    );
```

When I query the settings: get localhost:9200/index-name/_settings
the index.codec property is not set.

How can I set index.codec when creating a new index in ElasticSearch Nest 5.X

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: May you share `createIndexResponse.DebugInformation`?

Comment: @rob thanks for your reply: `Valid NEST response built from a successful low level call on PUT: /index-name
# Audit trail of this API call:
 - [1] HealthyResponse: Node: http://10.0.0.4:9200/ Took: 00:00:00.5095788
# Request:
{"settings":{"index.codec":"best_compression"},"mappings":{"conference":{"properties":{"confId":{"type":"long"},"publicationDate":{"type":"date"},[....],"id":{"type":"long"}}}}}
# Response:
{"acknowledged":true,"shards_acknowledged":true}`

Comment: Looks like index.codec has been set properly. Are you sure localhost == 10.0.0.4?